# How do I write a mysql subquery where one table returns multiple rows based from a table that returns one row?

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

Supposed that I have a table like this:

```
**tbl_purchase**
PurchaseID
Date
Supplier

**tbl_purchaseitem**
PurchaseItemID
PurchaseID
```

I want to create a query where it will return something like:

```
**Header**
PurchaseID = 2
Date: 4/26/12
Supplier:stackoverflow

*Items*
PurchaseItemID:3
PurchaseID:2

PurchaseItemID:4
PurchaseID:2

PurchaseItemID:5
PurchaseID:2
```

Sir/Ma'am your answers would be of great help and be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from tbl_purchase 
inner join 
tbl_purchaseitem
on 
tbl_purchase.PurchaseID = tbl_purchaseitem.PurchaseID
where 
PurchaseID = 2 
and 
Date = '4/26/12' 
and 
Supplier = 'stackoverflow'
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
SELECT pi.*
FROM tbl_purchase p
INNER JOIN tbl_purchaseitem pi
     ON p.PurchaseID = pi.PurchaseID
WHERE p.PurchaseID = 2 AND
      p.Date       = '2012-04-26' AND
      p.Supplier   = 'stackoverflow'
```